# Cofactor Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose that A is a 5x5 matrix with determinant 5, and when you delete the second row and fourth column, the determinant of the resulting matrix is -15. If B=A^-1, which entries of B can we determine with certainty.

I know to use the cofactor formula on this problem, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the second row and fourth column, the determinant of the resulting object is the minor $M_{2,4}$. The cofactor $C_{2,4} = (-1)^{2+4} M_{2,4} = -15$.

The cofactor formula says that

$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} C^T $$

So this means that the entry $B_{4,2} = \frac{1}{5} C_{2,4} = -3$.

Comment: Thanks man I love you I really needed this @Willie Wong